# Merging Node.js streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have a bunch of files that I read, process and merge certain data from corresponding multiple stream into a single stream.

Is there a more elegant solution than below (having a separate counter, calling `combinedStream.end()` after all source streams emit `end`):

```
let combinedStream = ....;

let counter = 0;

filePaths.forEach(function(filePath) {
  counter += 1;
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  const myStream = new MyStream(fileStream);

  myStream.on('data', myStream.write);
  myStream.on('end', function() {
    counter -= 1;
    if (counter === 0) {
      combinedStream.end();
    }
  });
});

return combinedStream;
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach could be the one used in that [repo](https://github.com/skypjack/common), even though it does nothing more than hiding your counter somewhere and let you deal with a more comfortable callbacks based model.

This way, your code will look like:

```
let sharedStream = ...

function onEachFilename(filename, callback) {
    // here you can read from the stream and push the data on the shared one,
    // then invoke the "internal" callback on the end event
}

function onEndAll() {
    // here you can finalize and close the shared stream
}

forEach(filenames, onEachFilename, onEndAll);
```

Keep in mind that somewhere there is still a function that is in charge to count for you and invoke the `onEnd` function once all the `callback` functions have been invoked.

Comment: Thanks.  I upvoted it as an alternative solution, but not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just process files  with a Transform stream then pipe to a PassThrough Stream.

Since, you are using `let`, I guess you can use ES2015.

```
  "use strict";

 let fs=require('fs');
 let filePaths=['./tmp/h.txt','./tmp/s.txt'];


 let Stream = require('stream');

  class StreamProcessor  {

   constructor() {
    this.process_streams = [];
   }

   push (source_stream) { 
   // Create a new Transform Stream
   let transform = new StreamTransformer();
    // Register the finish event and pipe
  transform.processed = transform.wait.call(transform);
   source_stream.pipe(transform);
   // push the stream to the internal array
  this.process_streams.push(transform);
   }

   done (callback) {  
    let streams = this.process_streams;
 // Wait for all Transform streams to finish processing
   Promise.all( 
   streams.map(function(s) {return s.processed; })
   )
   .then ( function() {
   let combined_stream=new Stream.PassThrough();
   streams.forEach(function (stream) {
   stream.pipe(combined_stream); 
   });
   // Call the callback with stream
    callback(null,combined_stream);
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
    callback(err);
    });
   }

   }     

  class StreamTransformer extends Stream.Transform {
     constructor () {
     // call super
     super();
     } 

     _transform(chunk,enc, transformed) {
     // process files here 
     let data=chunk.toString();
      data=data.substring(0,data.length-2);
     this.push(data);
     transformed();
     }

     _flush(flushed) {
     // for additonal at end
     this.push('\n');
     flushed();
     }

    wait() {
    // returns a promise that resolves, when all the data is processed;
    let stream = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject)  {
   stream.on('finish', function() {
   resolve(true); });
   stream.on('error', function(err) {
   reject(err);
   });
    });

    }

  }

  ///  Now you can do..

  let process_stream = new StreamProcessor(); 

   filePaths.forEach(function (fpath) {
   let fstream = fs.createReadStream(fpath);
   process_stream.push(fstream);
  });

   process_stream.done(  function
    (err,combined_stream) {
 // Consume the combines stream
 combined_stream.pipe(process.stdout);
  });
```

Test files contains 'hello' and 'stream'

```
     // Outputs is
    // hell
   // stream
```

This can be improved further..  . :/

Comment: Absolutely, by piping all the streams to the combined one, the end event will be invoked multiple times on the latter!! I guess it would be tricky for the component which is demanded to read from that stream...

Comment: @cswl As I said, I'm not piping whole files to the combined stream.  Only some data from the files is written to the combined streams `myStream.on('data', myStream.write)`, so I need to know when to close the combined stream.

Comment: @cswl thanks, but it looks more complicated, not simpler

Comment: @kyrylkov.  You can just put the classes on a seperate file and load it as a module.  Then your whole code becomes after the `// Now you can do`

Comment: @cswl Thanks.  I upvoted it as an alternative solution, but not the answer.

Comment: @kyrylkov   Well,  if you need to make you code **look** simpler in one place, you kinda have to put the complicated code somewhere else. in your program.   
If this solution doesnt fit your needs maybe we can work one another one.  
You also havent included how you have implemented the MyStream. Can you explain your problem in detail

Comment: @cswl It's just one place in the code.  My solution is quite easy to understand even for someone who doesn't deal with streams on a regular basis.  The details are the following: I have XML files from which I need to extract certain data and convert it to JSON as a first step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83663/discussion-between-cswl-and-kyrylkov).